# WebDriver for Python documentation

Tags: python, webdriver

I have already taken notice of [this piece of documentation](http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/index.html#). However, it seems to be missing large chunks, such as `Actions` objects.

Any idea where I can find more Python WebDriver documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the other site in which you can find the most up-to-date documentation is [seleniumhq.org](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) itself.

If you don't find what you need there, then probably you'll need to have a look at the docstrings in a python shell or at the source directly.